# What is the Unicode code for a grey ball?

Tags: unicode, colors

I am new to unicodes in general. It seems there are set unicode values for colored objects such as round balls.

[image]

https://www.gaijin.at/en/infos/unicode-character-table-geometry

Surely, there are codes for other colors?

I am after one for a grey-ball please, or a way to make one?

I am using direct javascript and I was hoping for a code so I don't have to use css as I am injecting this grey-ball into an existing web system that I did not build. Thanks

Comment: There are codes for other colors, but only black, white, red and blue. There is no gray. You might find amp-what is a useful place to search for Unicode characters with a certain characteristic [such as "circle"](https://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/circle) or ["ball"](https://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/ball).

Comment: Actually, I don't know why, but the LARGE WHITE CIRCLE unicode '&#x26AA;' is as close as I can get to "grey". It actually looks "greyish". Perfect.

Comment: FYI, [from the Unicode FAQs](https://unicode.org/faq/emoji_dingbats.html#6), with my emphasis added: _Q: What about characters whose names include WHITE or BLACK?_, _A: Names of symbols such as black medium square or white medium square **are not meant to indicate that the corresponding character must be presented in black or white**, respectively; rather, the use of “black” and “white” in the names is generally just to contrast filled versus outline shapes, or a darker color fill versus a lighter color fill._ I was surprised that U+26AA appeared grayish for you, but I guess this explains why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for either ⚪ or ⚫, which are "medium white/black" circles. The exact display depends on the font being used. You might also be interested in ⬤, which takes on the color of the text color.

Comparison:

| Character | Name |
| --- | --- |
| ⚪ | MEDIUM WHITE CIRCLE |
| ⚫ | MEDIUM BLACK CIRCLE |
| ⬤ | BLACK LARGE CIRCLE (takes on the color of the text) |

Comment: Why would the would the OP be looking for black or white circles when they explicitly stated they were looking for a gray one?

Comment: @skomisa They are **medium** white/black circles, not pure white/black circles. The medium qualifier makes them more grayish.

Comment: Gotcha. I just learned something.

Comment: Actually the white circle looks "greyish" to me on all browsers - perfect! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Other relevant Unicode codepoints containing LARGE and CIRCLE:

```
(9711, '◯', 'LARGE CIRCLE')
(11044, '⬤', 'BLACK LARGE CIRCLE')
(11093, '⭕', 'HEAVY LARGE CIRCLE')
(128308, '', 'LARGE RED CIRCLE')
(128309, '', 'LARGE BLUE CIRCLE')
```

No Unicode codepoint contains GREY or GRAY as of Unicode 13.0.0.

Also note that rendering is up to the font/browser.  BLACK LARGE CIRCLE is a text emoji so is not actually black but "solid" and is the color of the font.  On my system HEAVY LARGE CIRCLE happens to be a red unfilled circle.